# PHP PDO setAttribute and error handling

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding

I'm just a bit confused about PDO. Is it the correct form write a function like this for set attribute charset utf8 and for handling the database errors ?

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

thanks.

Comment: Just seen the accepted answer. If you get a parse error, don't waste everybody's time omitting that and asking something completely unrelated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple syntax error.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario,fancyPants my friends i was really confused about this function. It's not about parse errors. Now i'm starting to better realize how PDO works. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is just right except for a simple *syntactical* error. You missed a **comma**.

```
 $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password ,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
                                     //^----- You missed adding this
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=UTF8");
```

Or this is good as well

```
link = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb', 'login', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
```

Everything else is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of setting the encoding is only recommended in old PHP installations (older than PHP/5.3.6) but not *very* old—I don't remember the exact version but you had to run a `SET NAMES` query manually in really old versions where `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` wasn't implemented yet.

The recommended way is the appropriate parameter in the [DSN itself](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php):

> **charset**
>
> The character set. See the character set concepts documentation for
> more information.
>
> Prior to PHP 5.3.6, this element was silently ignored. The same
> behaviour can be partly replicated with the
> `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` driver option

Finally, you can set all settings at once in the constructor. There's no need to run a separate `setAttribute()` call.